# Trump administration and the war in Yemen

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, saudi-arabia, yemen

What is the Trump administration’s stance on Saudi Arabia’s war in Yemen? Does it differ from that of the previous administration?

Comment: http://foreignpolicy.com/2017/11/10/donald-trump-has-unleashed-the-saudi-arabia-we-always-wanted-and-feared/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The U.S. has [mostly provided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi_Arabian-led_intervention_in_Yemen#United_States) low key logistical support and remains a major arms supplier to Saudi Arabia, but has urged restraint in recent times. But, it has avoided a front line combat role and has not emphasized its involvement publicly.

One U.S. warship in the vicinity destroyed an anti-ship missile installation when it was fired upon, but not as part of a larger policy.

The Trump Administration's involvement continues the Obama Administration's involvement with little difference in practice but a somewhat more cautious tone.

Comment: There were drone strikes on AQAP, not sure if that counts

Answer (score 1):

According to this article Trump has gotten more aggressive with drone strikes and loosened the parameters increasing the potential for civilian casualties, definitely not more cautious:

www.newamerica.org/in-depth/americas-counterterrorism-wars/us-targeted-killing-program-yemen/